# CollectionView Cant change the frame of UIImageView

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimageview, uicollectionview

I've created at UICollectionView which contain a imageView. I want to resize this imageView to have the frame equal to the cells dimensions. i've tried using:

```
self.homeImage.frame =CGRectMake(0, 0, self.frame.size.width, self.frame.size.height);
```

in my CollectionViewCell subclass, but does not do anything for changing the size. How can i change the imageView Frame dynamically using code?

i've double checked that both datasource and delegate is connected. The outlet is also connected properly to the imageView.

## collectionViewCell subclass

```
- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame {
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
    if (self) {

    }
    return self;
}


 - (id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)aDecoder {
    self = [super initWithCoder:aDecoder];
    if (self) {

         self.homeImage.frame =CGRectMake(0, 0, self.frame.size.width, self.frame.size.height);

    }
    return self;
 }
```

## cellForItemAtIndexPath

```
- (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView
              cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {


    static NSString *identifier = @"Cell";

    FRGWaterfallCollectionViewCell *cell = [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:identifier forIndexPath:indexPath];



    UIImage *theImage = [[homesDic objectAtIndex:indexPath.item] objectForKey:@"image"];

    cell.homeImage.image = theImage;

    cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];


    return cell;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
- (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

{

```
static NSString *identifier = @"cell";    
UICollectionViewCell *cell=[collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:identifier forIndexPath:indexPath];    
if (cell == nil)    
{    

        cell = [[UICollectionViewCell alloc] init];    
}    
for (UIView *v in [cell subviews])       
{    

    if ([v isKindOfClass:[UIView class]])  { 

        [v removeFromSuperview];    
    }    

}    
UIImageView *imgMiddleView;    
imgMiddleView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:cell.frame];    
imgMiddleView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleToFill;    
imgMiddleView.clipsToBounds = YES;    
[imgMiddleView setUserInteractionEnabled:YES];    
imgMiddleView.tag = indexPath.row;    

[cell addSubview:imgMiddleView];    

return cell;
```

}

Answer (score 1):

Uncheck the `Autolayout` in  `FRGWaterfallCollectionViewCell.xib` file